# Python can import a module that isn't installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import

So, I'm playing around with packaging a python script I've written, and it has a submodule, let's call it `submodule`. The folder structure looks like this:

```
cool_script/
  setup.py
  cool_script.py
  submodule/
    __init__.py
    implementation.py
```

Now, after many `pip install .` and `pip install -e .` calls, I have the situation where `submodule` can be imported globally. No matter where on my system, this will always work:

```
$ python3
[...]
>>> import submodule
>>> submodule.__file__
'/home/me/fake/path/cool_script/submodule/__init__.py'
```

*But I don't know why.*

The package I made was uninstalled again, and pip cannot find the submodule in its index. There's nothing in dist-packages either, I manually deleted the `cool_script.egg-link` that was still sitting around there:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages | ack cool 
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages | ack submodule
$
```

The `PYTHONPATH` is empty as well:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH

$
```

*Why does Python know the location of `submodule`? How can I find out?*

Comment: Was it installed in a virtualenv? Is it a linux system?

Comment: This is a linux system indeed, and no, I did these experiments on my global environment. I know that was very dumb. Lesson learned, I guess.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but have you tried rebooting? Maybe it is just cached somewhere

Comment: What happens when you import your submodule? Do you get an error?

Comment: The answer to "How can I find out?" would be `sys.path` I guess. The current working directory is in there, too, so are you sure it's not just that you did that `import submodule` from `cool_script` folder itself?

Comment: @RunOrVeith I have not. I'll do that when I'm done with work for today.

Comment: @AmitTripathi As my post shows, the submodule imports flawlessly.

Comment: @Jeronimo Aha, we've got a lead there, `/home/me/fake/path/cool_script` is indeed in `sys.path`! So we're one step closer, but it's still unclear how it got there. Might `pip install -e .` be responsible for that?

Comment: And it's not the cwd?

Comment: @Jeronimo Nope, this works from any directory on my machine.

Comment: @RunOrVeith So I did reboot now, that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First run `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`. It will print a list like this:

```
['/XXX/something/site-packages']
```

Normally there is a single path in this list, and it points to a directory where `pip` installs your scripts.  You can `ls` into it if you're curious: `ls /XXX/something/site-packages/`.

More interestingly, though, `pip` puts a "link" file in that directory when you're using developer installs (a.k.a. `pip install -e`).  The "link" file is named after the original project with a `.egg-link` extension at the end.

So you probably have a `cool_script.egg-link` file in that directory.  And if you try to print it out you should find that its contents list the original filesystem location of your module.  Something like:

```
$ cat /XXX/something/site-packages/cool_script.egg-link
/home/me/fake/path/cool_script/
.
```

This is how `pip` records that it has installed something in developer mode, but it isn't how Python actually knows how to find your module (that would have been too easy, right? :-)).

Python doesn't know about `.egg-link` files, but it reads all `.pth` files in the `site-packages` directory to get additional paths for `sys.path` (*).  So, for Python to be able to import developer mode installs, `pip` writes all theirs paths in a single `.pth` file conventionally called `easy-install.pth` (because the old `easy-install` tool actually pioneered that technique).  And if you print out that file, you'll get the list of *all* projects paths installed in developer mode:

```
$ cat /XXX/something/site-packages/easy-install.pth
/home/me/fake/path/cool_script/
/home/me/another/project/
```

And you can check that indeed all those paths listed in `easy-install.pth` indeed get added to your `sys.path`.

(*) Technically, the part of Python that reads those `.pth` file is the `site` module which is normally imported automatically at startup.  There is an option to disable the `site` module, though, for example by using `python -S`.  In that case, you'll see that `sys.path` contains neither the `site-packages` directory nor the developer install paths.

Comment: That's it, the folder was listed in `easy-install.pth`. Removing it solved the problem! Thanks for the thorough explanation.